# Highcharts export not displaying correctly

Tags: svg, highcharts, export

I have a slight problem with my HighCharts export.

They main and only issue is that the chart that I'm exporting is now exported properly, mainly the labels.

How it should look:
http://s22.postimg.org/5d1oh16y9/image_1_proper.png

How it looks as SVG export:
http://s9.postimg.org/71qijdhhr/image_1_svg.png

How it looks as PNG export:
s27.postimg.org/5fq5tfgdv/image_1_png.png

I tried using chart.redraw() and the export it with chart.exportChart() and it gave me the same results

To display the labels I'm using: plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter

```
settings.plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter=function(){
        if(this.point.z!=0.3){
            return "<a style='position:relative;top:10px;text-align:center; text-shadow: none; color:black;'>"+this.point.name+"</a>";
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

TNX

Comment: Most probably you have set `useHTML` option to true, which is not supported in exporting: [source](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting). Exporting server requires only SVG, not HTML.

Comment: Okey yes, but that didn't solve my problem correctly. Now my original looks like SVG so that means that my labels aren't rendered. Is there a way to to render them?

Comment: [Allow overlapping](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) for the dataLabels?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Paweł Fus <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602207/highcharts-export-not-displaying-correctly#comment45512180_28602207) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602207/highcharts-export-not-displaying-correctly#comment45512708_28602207)</sup>, you should also set both [`useHTML`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.useHTML) and [`allowOverlap`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap) to `true`:

```
settings.plotOptions.series.dataLabels = {
    useHTML: true,
    allowOverlap: true,
    formatter: function() {
        if(this.point.z!=0.3){
            return "<a style='position:relative;top:10px;text-align:center; text-shadow: none; color:black;'>"+this.point.name+"</a>";
        }
    }
}
```